# Limit inlines to edit mode in Django's ModelAdmin

Tags: django, django-admin

How can you limit Django's ModelAdmin inlines to edit mode. This is what I tried but it does not work:

```
class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = PageModelForm

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PageAdmin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance.pk:
            self.inlines = (FileInLine, )
```

In other word, I would like to access the instance in the ModelAdmin to determine whether pk is set and only in that case shows the inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = PageModelForm
    inlines = [FileInLine]

    def get_formsets_with_inlines(self, request, obj=None):
        for inline in self.get_inline_instances(request, obj):
            if isinstance(inline, FileInLine) and obj is None:
                continue
            yield inline.get_formset(request, obj), inline
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_formsets_with_inlines